# Short story where people can die and are revived in bed through high tech and need legal permission to die

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this story in an American anthology, sometime between 1990-2010. A woman who likes extreme sports, such as dropping to Earth from near-orbit. As she falls, she burns up and dies. Then she is revived in bed, perfectly healthy and sane, just like everyone else on earth - humans have invented immortality. Because of this, murder is a misdemeanor. I also remember details like people need special permission to die permanently, and that the woman protagonist attacked her mother... with an axe I think? I'm fairly sure this was not a Robert Silverberg story.

Well, I found it. It was "Suicidal Tendencies" by Dave Smeds, published in the anthology Full Spectrum 4 in 1994. The protagonist is the mother, but she does indeed get attacked by her axe-wielding daughter in the first paragraph.

Comment: The first few sentences sound a lot like the opening to "pandora's star" and the events of Justine Burnelli, can you remember any other details like the year(s) it was set?

Comment: It was set on Earth, in a future time - but all I can remember about the technology level is that people's beds could recreate their bodies and insert memories from a recording device in their brains. It was mostly about this daughter's relationship with her mother, and how the resurrections affected that.

Comment: Sounds vaguely similar to The Metamorphosis Of Prime Intellect,

Comment: @Bill Galloway - Glad you found the story you were looking for, but the practice here is to post answers via the 'Your Answer' field below, rather than editing them into a question. If you post the answer yourself, you could earn some additional upvotes and reputation for it. If you wait too long though, someone else will likely post the answer themselves. Either way, we'd be grateful if you'd mark the answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), as it's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

Comment: You can mark an answer as accepted by clicking on the grey checkmark near the top-left corner of the answer. It will turn green if you've done it correctly. Do note that if you post the answer yourself, the site won't allow you to mark the answer as accepted until the question is 48 hours old, as that's the policy with 'self-answers' here. If another user posts the answer though, you can mark it as accepted whenever you like.

Comment: @BillGalloway: I've posted an answer, but if you post your own, I'm glad to delete mine. And, of course, you're welcome to borrow any or all of my text for your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

The querent located the story, "Suicidal Tendencies" ([ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40907)) by Dave Smeds, published in the anthology *[Full Spectrum 4](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3221060)* in 1994. The protagonist is the mother, but she does indeed get attacked by her axe-wielding daughter in the first paragraph.

From [this review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/3426265421):

> In defiance of its title, "Suicidal Tendencies" by Dave Smeds is a light-hearted story about the games people would play, when they have all the time in the world. This one also has a lot of local color for me now, although I missed that my first time around...